# Retrieving binary with "allow external storage" enabled

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am storing image data in Core Data.
When I fetch an entity every property is populated correctly except the Binary Data property with "Allows External Storage" enabled (the image).
Instead of the saved data it is populated by some weird data, and can't be resolved to an image.

If I disable "Allows External Storage" and retry the process of saving and retrieving the Binary Data property is populated correctly and the image can be resolved correctly from the data.

Is there something I need to do when "Allows External Storage" is enabled ?

Fetching snippet, the AssetDownloadTaskEntity has an image property NSData? which is the Binary Data in question:

```
do {
   let fetch: NSFetchRequest<AssetDownloadTaskEntity> = AssetDownloadTaskEntity.fetchRequest()
   fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier LIKE %@", identifier)
   fetch.fetchLimit = 1

   let result = try moc.fetch(fetch).first
   completion(result, nil)
}
catch {
   completion(nil, error)
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be. It's hard to guess what might be wrong without more detail, like code showing how you're setting/retrieving this data and what the "weird data" looks like.

Comment: @TomHarrington added some extra information.

Comment: Yeah, some. It would still be useful to know what, specifically you are getting back that's not what you expect. And how you're saving the data. That code is just a standard fetch request.